# Dynamic Carousel In Laravel not displaying proper data

Tags: laravel

```
<div class="container mt-4 mb-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="blogCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox"> 
                    @foreach($reviews as $items)
                            <div class="carousel-item @if($loop->first) active @endif">
                                <div class="row">
                                    @foreach($reviews as $review)
                                        <div class="col-lg-4 ">
                                            <a>                                 
                                                <div class="home1-img mt-3">
                                                    <?php 
                                                        for($i=1;$i<6;$i++){
                                                            $check = '';
                                                            if($review->number_of_stars >= $i){
                                                                $check = 'checked';
                                                            }
                                                            echo '<span class="fa fa-star '.$check.'"></span>';
                                                        }
                                                    ?>
                                                    <div class="home1-text mt-1" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
                                                        
                                                        <p>{!! Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($review->customer_review,100) !!}</p>
                                                        <h5 class="text-color font-weight-bold">{{ $review->customer_name }}</h5>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    @endforeach
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    @endforeach
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am getting all the records in all sides but I want 3 records in 1st slide then 3 records in 2nd slide and so on. I have tried many times but I am not able to fix it.

Comment: did you tried the way i answered in your same question before??

Comment: Yes, it didn't worked for me:-)

Comment: what did not work?? what are you getting?? have you tried to debug??

Comment: Yes I tried debugging it, it shows all the data in 1st slide and then also same data in other slides:-)

Comment: then you didn't chunk the data at all..

Comment: Oh I forgot that, now its working properly. Thank you for your help:-)

Comment: then check my answer on the previous question as accepted.